# Python os.system & subprocess do not recognize Microsoft's ie4uinit.exe

Tags: subprocess, python-3.4, windows-7-x64, os.system

I'm trying to call ie4uinit from a python script so that I can update the icon in my task bar.  ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache does just that, however whenever python calls it, either with subprocess.call or os.system, the following error comes up and the program is not called.

> "ie4uinit.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I have tried giving the full path location i.e.

> "C:\Windows\System32\ie4uinit.exe"

Same result.
I have even made a .bat to abstract the call.

I suspect the problem is stemming from a difference in permissions between calling the command from the command line, and calling it through python.
 But I don't know how.

Comment: Probably you're running a 32-bit version of Python.  Try `c:\windows\sysnative\ie4unit.exe`

Comment: Yea, I am running a 32-bit version of Python, but the ie4unit.exe doesn't seem to exist.  Nore does the Sysnative folder.  There is SysWOW64, but that is devoid of the ie4unit.exe.

Comment: Also, I can't imagine why a 32bit program can't call a 64bit one.

Comment: `sysnative` isn't a folder, it is a special instruction to the 32-bit emulator.  It will work, try it.  See [WoW64 - Registry and File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64#Registry_and_file_system) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Yep `\sysnative\ie4uinit.exe` worked!  Thanks Harry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python os.listdir doesn't show all files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271306/python-os-listdir-doesnt-show-all-files)